# Spring javax.validation problem

Tags: java, spring

In my application with spring framework, I have this import which it couldn't find

```
 import javax.validation.Valid;
```

Thing is I already have that javax.jar in the classpath. So my question is is there a different version of javax.jar that has validation package or I need any other jar files?
   I couldn't find any javax.jar that has validation package on the internet. So please give me a link if you know any. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [javax.validation:validation-api](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.validation%7Cvalidation-api%7C1.0.0.GA%7Cjar).

Also, as Amir mentioned, if you've found stackoverflow useful, accept some answers. People will be more inclined to help out.

Answer (score 0):

`javax.validation.*` is part of jsr-303 which needs to be downloaded separately [here](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, just add the external dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Verify the latest version here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api